# xamarin ios publish error - Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing

Tags: xamarin.ios, info.plist, ios-icons

I've been trying to fix this for days now.  Using Xamarin and Visual Studio, I deleted the asset `catalogs/media` folder then I used app icon set creator to create the icons.  I then went into `info.plist` under visual assets and hit add catalog, then dragged the icons into the slots.

No matter how many times I try this I get the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

thanks!!!!

> Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
>   'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have used **Asset Catalog** to create your app's icons. You have to add all the icon files in the AppIcons of Media Catalog, because after XCode 9 we need to provide App Store icon sized 1024x1024 within the Xcode itself.

After doing that, you can add the `CFBundleIconName` key in your info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

But there may be an error on Visual Studio 2017 15.6+ when we add **Asset Catalog**. Open your info.plist you will see

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

Then look at your project's folder you will find your Catalogs file `Media.xcassets` locating in your root project directory outside of `Resources` folder. So we need to modify the key `XSAppIconAssets` to show the icons:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

This [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103652/missing-info-plist-value-cfbundleiconname-after-xamarin-update-how-can-i-fix-it) lists more solutions about the same issue. You can refer to it for more details.

Comment: that was it... the key string that was automatically generated was pointing to an incorrect location.  once I fixed this it worked.  thanks!!!!